# How can I add an array of users to the channel rights? Discord.JS v14 | NEST JS

Tags: discord, discord.js, nestjs, nest

I ran into a problem. I want to add an array of users to the channel rights. Everything is fine on pure js. But as soon as I do it on nestjs (typescript), it throws an error - `Type '{ id: string; allow: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'OverwriteResolvable'`.

**Code:**

```
let stagechannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get('1012807170393378927')
let ticketsSupportRoles = [
  "772447005297475626",
]
let supportRoles = ticketsSupportRoles.map(x => {
   return {
    id: x,
    allow: ["ViewChannel"]
   };
})
              
stagechannel.edit({
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
       id: interaction.guild.id,
       allow: ['Connect', 'ViewChannel'],
       deny: ['MoveMembers', 'ModerateMembers', 'MuteMembers', 'ManageChannels', 'MentionEveryone']
    },
    ...supportRoles
  ],
})
```

Complains about - supportRoles (`Type '{ id: string; allow: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'OverwriteResolvable'.`)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a while and my solution, which I'm not sure if it was the best, was to add the type `'Array<overwriteData>'` to **"supportRoles"**

```
let supportRoles: Array<overwriteData> = ticketsSupportRoles.map(x => {
   return {
    id: x,
    allow: ["ViewChannel"]
   };
})
```